# Create points from shape

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to draw around 3D elements of an object to make them selectable.

In a 2D shape it's pretty easy using Shap.

```
    const shape = new Shape();
if (!points.length) return shape;
for (const point of points) shape.lineTo(point[0], point[1]);
if (mousePos) shape.lineTo(mousePos[0], mousePos[1]);

return shape;
```

I was thinking in 3D I could draw around the entities with the mouse, fill in the gaps with a point cloud, iterative other each point with the raycaster to so it is adjusted to the point nearest the camera that intersects with the mesh and I should have a points shape that fits the underlying mesh.

My question is - if I have a Shape what is the easiest way to create points to cover the area of the shape so I can find the point closest to the camera?

Answer (score 0):

- use `BufferGeometry` and `PointMaterial` to express particle point.
- points require vertices with z position. give them Z position.

```js
import * as T from 'three';

const points = [x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3...]; /*... your points in 2d ...*/
const shape = new T.Shape(/* ... your shape from points ... */);

const z = 3; // any z position you want
// because `THREE.Shape` is in 2D, give it a Z position from the shape
const vertices = new Float32Array(points.reduce((ac, cv) => ([...ac, ...cv, z]), []);

const geometry = new T.BufferGeometry();
geometry.setAttribute( 'position', new T.BufferAttribute( vertices, 3 ) );
const material = new T.PointsMaterial({ color: new T.Color('red') });
const mesh = new T.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);
```

https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=shape#api/en/core/BufferGeometry

Edit: `points` array is flattened array of [x,y].   `vertices` array is flattened array of [x,y,z].

Comment: Great thanks.  I'm trying to create rows and columns of points within the shape so I can raycast those. So I think this function takes the existing points from the existing shape? I need to add all the points in between those points.

Comment: @GrandMassive I have elaborated code example so that you can understand better. yes, the function takes X and Y from source of `THREE.Shape` points, and adds z to each points. `points` is basically a flattened array of 2 dimensional position [x,y]. `vertices` is a flattened array of 3 dimensional positions.

Comment: Thanks. Yea I get that. It's a grid of points between these points I'm trying to get. But you've given me an idea, convert this to triangles and add points along the lines of the triangles.